# How to ensure message consistency when using futures in Akka

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka

I would like to understand how to work with a stateful actor when I have async calls within the action.

Consider the following actor:

```
@Singleton
class MyActor @Inject() () extends Actor with LazyLogging  {
  import context.dispatcher
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Test(id: String) =>
      Future { logger.debug(s"id [$id]") }
    }
}
```

and a call to this actor:

```
Stream.range(1, 100).foreach { i =>
  MyActor ! Test(i.toString)
}
```

This will give me an inconsistent printing of the series.

How am I supposed to use futures inside an actor without loosing the entire "one message after another" functionality?

Comment: If you put something like `println(s"received $id") ` just before your `Future` part... you should see the id getting there in the correct order, right?

Answer (score 2):

You should store that Future in a `var` then on every next message you should make a flatMap call.

```
if(storedFut == null) storedFut = Future { logger.debug(s"id [$id]") }
else storedFut = storedFut.flatMap(_ => Future { logger.debug(s"id [$id]") })
```

`flatMap` is exactly for ordering of Futures.

**Sidenote**

If you want thing to happen in parallel you're in the nondeterministic zone, where you cannot impose ordering

Comment: Not really sure if this is genius or extremely bad

Comment: It really depends what you want to achieve. Futures are asynchronous and scheduled on executor can take arbitrary long time so if you don't `flatMap` you loose ordering. In most cases I've seen `Future` computes some values and this value is then send back to original actor or some other. In that case you can use `pipeTo`. When you send it back it's up to your actor to keep the ordering, so you can e.g. hold a global counter and for every message increment it and attach it to Future using `map` for example.

Comment: Something smells of memory leak from this thing, what's going to happen to all the tons of completed futures in that chain?

Comment: That is indeed a very good question. When you `flatMap` on `Future` you're crossing the async boundary since your method is being submited to `ExecutionContext`. Mind the second curried argument to `flatMap`. So it's not going to overflow the stack, and it's will not leak memory. Old Futures when unreferenced will be subject to normal GC activity cleanups.

Answer (score 2):

What you're observing is not a violation of Akka's ["message ordering per sender–receiver pair"](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/general/message-delivery-reliability.html#the-general-rules) guarantee; what you're observing is the nondeterministic nature of `Future`s, as @almendar mentions in his or her answer.

The `Test` messages are being sent to `MyActor` sequentially, from `Test("1")` to `Test("100")`, and `MyActor` *is* processing each message in its `receive` block in that same order. However, you're logging each message inside a `Future`, and the order in which those `Futures` are completed is nondeterministic. This is why you see the "inconsistent printing of the series."

To get the desired behavior of sequential logging of the messages, don't wrap the logging in a `Future`. If you must use a `Future` inside an actor's `receive` block, then @almendar's approach of using a `var` inside the actor is safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use context.become and stash messages, wait for the end of the future and process another message. 
More about how to use stash with example you can find in documentation http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/Stash.html

Remember - messages ordering is guarantee only if messages are sent from the same machine because of network characteristic.

Answer (score -1):

Another way would be to send itself a message on `Future.onComplete` assuming that there are no restrictions on the order of processing

```
    //in receive  
    val future = Future { logger.debug(s"id [$id]") }
    f.onComplete {
        case Success(value) => self ! TestResult(s"Got the callback, meaning = $value")
        case Failure(e) => self ! TestError(e)
      }
```

Comment: Because the futures would not be completed by any order, the TestResults would not be ordered as well